# How to pass JSON string to another api using RESTSharp?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, json.net, restsharp

Problem Specification:

> Resource URI :     `address/index.php?r=api/employee`
>
> Request Header : `Content- Type: application/json`
>
> HTTP Method: `POST`
>
> Request Body: `{ "employeeName" : "ABC","age":"20","ContactNumber": "12341234"}`

The above parameters should be passed to the system as a row HTTP POST in a JSON string.

I am trying to solve this problem using `RESTSharp`. But I am having some problem Like after executing the request my code return a Null response and I am not sure my JSON string is passing properly or not.

Here is my Code:

```
public ActionResult EmployeeInfo(Employee employee)
    {
        //string empName = unSubscription.employeeName.ToString();

        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:21779/");

        var request = new RestRequest("api/employee ", Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddBody(new Employee
        {
            employeeName = "ABC",
            age = "20",
            ContactNumber = "12341234"
        });


        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", @"application/json");
      

        // execute the request
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

        return View();
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code??

And I am little bit confused about

```
  request.AddUrlSegment("username", "Admin") and request.AddParameter("name", "value").
```

Basically I want to know how to utilize `AdduUrlSegment()` and `AddParameter()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using `request.AddUrlSegment("username", "Admin")` you should define your url template properly: `var request = new RestRequest("api/employee/{username} ", Method.POST);`

Also you should set `Content-Type`

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", @"application/json");
```

befor adding a **Body**

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. I found that there is no problem in my code. Its working fine. :)